# Json.net JsonPath filters with unions

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to dynamically build a JsonPath to find elements in an array based on all their properties. Using a static linq query is not an option because my code needs to work with any array. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2 in my C#.net project.

I'm trying with the JsonPath below but I'm getting an `Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: ,` exception. Seems to work on the jsonpath.curiousconcept.com JsonPath tester using any Flow Communications version.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

JsonPath: `$.arr[?(@.Amount == '1000'),?(@.Name == 'Item A')]`

Json:

`{
  "arr":[
    {
      "Name":"Item A",
      "Amount":1000
    },
    {
      "Name":"Item B",
      "Amount":2000
    },
    {
      "Name":"Item C",
      "Amount":3000
    },
    {
      "Name":"Item D",
      "Amount":4000
    }
  ]
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume on the jsonpath.curiousconcept.com the second part is just ignored. Correct JsonPath is:

```
$.arr[?(@.Amount == 1000 && @.Name == 'Item A')]
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! That worked, but I had to remove the quotes from the Amount value. so correct for my example is `$.arr[?(@.Amount == 1000 && @.Name == 'Item A')]`